# ssis how to automatically get all columns for union all

Tags: ssis, union-all

I have about 20 data sources to union in current packages. When using "Union All", it will import columns from the first connected data source. Then I have to manually add columns from other 19 data sources which are not contained in the first one.

Is there any approach or work around to automatically get all columns from all data sources for "UNION ALL", or at least faster?

*P.S. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL server 2012.*

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no feature for that. You could add a feature request for it at msconnect: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback